# Reverse a linked list recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to achieve a reversed link list. The new fresh list  must be created recursively.

I am creating the first node in the reversed list and I am trying to create a sublist Next which has the next element as next.next and finally to assign this sublist as next to the node. The issue is that the next node remains NIL although I recreated it in the for loop.

Edit: 
The function must not change (add arguments) because some tests are running upon it.

```
class Node {
    private Object item;
    private Node next,current;

    public Node(Object o, Node n) {
        this.item = o;
        this.next = n;
    } 

    public Node(Node n) {
    }

    public static final Node NIL = new Node(Node.NIL, Node.NIL);

    public Object getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setItem(Object o) {
        this.item = o;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        this.next = n;
    }

    // this method returns the item with index number i
    public Object nthItem(int i) {
        Node p = this;
        while (p!=null){
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++){
                p=p.next; 
            }
            return p.item;
        }
        return null;  
    }

    // this method returns the the next item of the node
    public Node nthNext(int i) {
        Node p = this;
        while (p!=null){
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++){
                p=p.next; 
            }
            return p.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Node nthNode(int i) {
        Node p = this;
        while (p!=null){
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++){
                p=p.next; 
            }
            return p;
        }
        return NIL;  
    }

    public int length(){
        if (this == NIL) return 0;
        else return 1 + next.length();
    }

    public Node remove(Object o){
        Node p = this;
        if (p == NIL) return NIL;
        else if(p.item == o) {
            p = p.next;
            return p.remove(o);
        } 
        else return new Node(p.item, p.next.remove(o)); 
    }

    public Node reverse() {
        int i = this.length()-1;
        if(this == NIL) return NIL;

        Node node = new Node(Node.NIL, Node.NIL);

        Node next = NIL;

        //create the first node in the reversed list
        if(i >= 1) node = new Node(nthItem(i), next);
        else node = new Node(nthItem(i), Node.NIL);

        //iterate through the original list and create a next node
        if (i>0) {
            for (int k=i; k>=0; k--){
                if (k<=0)  {
                    next = NIL;
                }
                else {
                    next = new Node(nthItem(k-1),next);
                }               
            }
        }

        //debugging in console
        System.out.println("final node = " + next.item+" ");
        return node;
    }
}

class Test{

    public static void main(String[] string){
        Node n = new Node(1, Node.NIL);
        Node nn = new Node(2, n);

        Node r = nn.reverse();

        System.out.println("\t item " + r.getItem()+ " " + r.getNext().getItem() + " length " + r.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not recursing unless your `reverse` method calls your `reverse` method.

Comment: Side note, current should not be a field of node.

Comment: It is not yet recursive function because I don't how to do it as long as it has not any aguments. I forgot to mention that this function must not change the arguments because tests are running on it. I edited now the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question designed to test whether you understand the implicit stack.
Each time you make a recursive call, you add a stack frame, so consider the stack as if you were performing the routine iteratively.

To reverse the list:

1. Stack all elements in order
2. Make a new list by popping each element.

Now convert this to a recursive call

```
//in [1,2,3,null]
Node reverse(Node n){

    //base case
    if(n == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // returns [null,3,2,1]
    Node next = reverse(n.getNext());
    next.setNext(n);// set the next nodes next to its previous(n on unwinding)
    return n;
}
```

Note that the reverse method here doesn't return the new head, to get the head of the reversed list do the following, maybe making a the above a helper instead.

```
Node oldHead = n;
Node newHead = tail(n);
oldHead.reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was really helpful and finally after a white I understood totally how the recursion works